# How to line up the contents of drop down with the button - bootstrap

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to do something that I would expect to be pretty straightforward.  I simply want to have a drop down list centered on the page.  THe problem is when it is expanded the contents are not lined up with the button.  Here is the example: http://jsfiddle.net/VCsAW/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the CSS add the following:

```
#settings {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

This will force the `#settings` div to fit to the size of the contents and resolve the 'offset' dropdown

**Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/VCsAW/8/**

**Edit**

The reason the contents are centered is due to the `text-align: center` being used to center the dropdown menu. To stop this from happening in the contents of the dropdown menu, you can just set `text-align: center` in `.dopdown-menu`:

```
.dropdown-menu {
     text-align: left;    
}
```

**Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/VCsAW/12/**

Comment: this works well, only issue is the contents of the drop down list are aligned center.  i want them to be aligned left.